# React Native useRef returns undefined on iOS and Android but works on Web

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, ref

I build a website with React Native and used `useRef` for scrolling to a specific element with `scrollIntoView`.

On web I have this code:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { View, ScrollView, Text } from 'react-native';

//Components
import Header from '../components/header';
import MenuBar from '../components/menubar';

export default function Reserveren({ navigation, route }) {

const reserveRef = useRef();

const scrollToElement = (ref) => {
   ref.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
}

return (
   <View>
    <ScrollView>

     <Header navigation={navigation} />
     <MenuBar navigation={navigation} />

    
    <View>
      <Button title="Click me to scroll" onPress={scrollToElement(reserveRef)} />
    </View>

   <View ref={reserveRef}>
     <Text>This is the element to scroll to</Text>
   </View>

  </ScrollView>
</View>
)


}
```

This code works perfectly fine on web but running the same code on iOS and Android gives me a `undefined`. What am I doing wrong? Searched for hours on the web but couldn't find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

> `onPress={scrollToElement(reserveRef)}`

You are calling the `scrollToElement` function during the rendering of the component, instead of calling it when the user presses the button.

To handle a button press, you must pass a function to `onPress`, e.g.:
`onPress={() => scrollToElement(reserveRef)}`

Note that refs to elements are always `undefined` during the initial render.